# How to access a table record by id of another table in many to many relationship in django?

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, django-models

Here is my model :

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_eng = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.genre_eng)
```

and here is my view method :

```
def info(request, id):
    movie_info = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'info.html', {'movie_info': movie_info})
```

I can already print the name of the movie like this in `info.html` file:

```
genre : {{movie_info.title}}
```

How Can I access the `genre_eng` in the `info.html` file?

each movie may have multiple genres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access all the **Genre** associated with ***Movie*** instance, 
use **`movie_info.genre.all()`**. If you want to access **`genre_eng`** use [**`.values_list()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
def info(request, id):
    movie_info = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
    genre_eng_queryset = movie_info.genre.all()
    genre_eng_values = movie_info.genre.values_list('genre_eng', flat=True)
    return render(request, 'info.html',
                  {'movie_info': movie_info, 'genre_eng_queryset': genre_eng_queryset, 'genre_eng_values': genre_eng_values})
```

Comment: Thank you JPG.and how can I retrieve them in the template? do I need a for loop?

Comment: Yeah, both are kind of ***list*** objects